# flash as3 - create an array of coordinate points

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I want to create a simple array of points, representing a clockwise set of coordinates at 45 degree increments, such that the array would be (starting from 12 o'clock):

```
var coordArray : Array = [
                  new Point(0,-1),
                  new Point(1,-1),
                  new Point(1,0),
                  new Point(1,1),
                  new Point(0,1),
                  new Point(-1,1),
                  new Point(-1,0),
                  new Point(-1,-1)
                  ];
```

I'm looking for the most efficient way of creating this array (ideally with the coordinates themselves generated through some sort of equation). What's the best way to do this? All I want to do with these is create a coordinate on the stage relative to the clips current coordinate in which to move, based on that clips, such that if the move distance for clips was 50px, and the clip had a depth of 0, it would move 50px in the coordArray[0] position, or 0*50 in the x direction, and -50px in the y direction (0,-1).

Comment: More details please. Are you wanting to generate these points by decomposing polygons? What is your exact implementation? If you want the best answer, you need to give more information :D

Comment: Is it for a game of some kind?

Comment: Sort of - it's for a visual interface - a way of navigating a sort of tree diagram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var points:Array = [];
var length:int = 50;
var angle:int = 45;
for(var i:int = 0; i < 360 / angle; i++)
{
  radian:Number = i * angle * Math.PI / 180;
  var p:Point = new Point(Math.cos(radian) * length, Math.sin(radian) * length);
  points.push(p);     
}
```

For example, you have a `clip` and want it to move `var speed:int = 50`px at `var angle:int = 36`degree.

```
radian:Number = angle * Math.PI / 180;
clip.x += Math.cos(radian) * speed;
clip.y += Math.sin(radian) * speed;
```

Comment: @mheavers, hey, I've fixed some typos. It works now - I've checked.

Comment: Edited my answer once again. I always forget, that Math.sin/cos accept angle in radians. This time it really works :)

Comment: There's a few redundant parts to your code. You could save the `180 / Math.PI` (not `Math.PI / 180`) result in a local variable (toss it under the 3rd line `var a:int...` as `var radian:Number` for example), and within the for-loop scope you could store the result of `i * a * radian` and replace that in `Math.cos(angle)` and `Math.sin(angle)`.

Comment: Sure, there's a huge potential for optimization. In my projects I use static functions G.radian(degree) and G.degree(radian). Going further, there's no need in local variable `p`. But I guess I'll leave it like this for the sake of simplicity. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: No prob! Yeah a global static function (like you mentioned) would be the next step to optimize this further once the algorithm is setup. Some might debate that an extra function call within a loop is not recommended, but I would favor that over inserting duplicate code everywhere! Definitely improves readibility :)